# Communicate Between Fetch POST And ColdFusion Function With CfHttp

Tags: coldfusion, fetch-api

While I understand that `fetch()` requests can have parameters, in the form of "headers:", "body:", etc., I'm having trouble with a `fetch()` POST call to a ColdFusion Component remote function.
My fetch call is:

```
fetch('myComponent.cfc?method=createObj', {method: "POST", body: jsonVar }) 
   .then(function (getCreateResponse) {
       //do great things
})
.catch(function err) {
alert("Fetch error: " + err);
});
```

My cfc function looks like:

```
   remote array function createObj(required any myObj) returnFormat = "JSON" {
           cfhttp(url="http://myServer/ObjAPI/Obj", method="POST", result="getResponse") {
            cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/json");
            cfhttpparam(type="body", value=SerializeJSON(myObj));
        } }
```

(This POST takes a RequestBody with the JSON.) When I run this code, I am told in my CFC logs:

> "The MYOBJ parameter to the createObj function is required but was not passed in."

When I remove the parameter from the createObj function, the fetch call fails and  I am told:

> "Variable MYOBJ is undefined."

It appears to me that the CF Function needs a parameter in order to know what it should send in the cfhttp call; however, it's not recognizing the "body: jsonVar" parameter sent by the fetch call. Is there another way to send a parameter that the CF function would understand?

Comment: what if you surrounded this, `{method: "POST", body: jsonVar }`, with brackets, took away the comma.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm afraid I don't quite understand the suggestion; wrap what already has brackets with brackets? The comma also has to be there, otherwise I get an error.

Comment: I wouldn't use fetch for this or anything.  Fetch is not supported by IE thus your site will not be cross browser capable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the data as `body` data. You can see the json data as below

```
remote array function createObj() returnFormat = "JSON" {
     WriteDump(deserializeJSON(ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content)));
     myObj =  deserializeJSON(ToString(getHTTPRequestData().content));
     cfhttp(url="http://myServer/ObjAPI/Obj", method="POST", result="getResponse") {
         cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/json");
         cfhttpparam(type="body", value=SerializeJSON(myObj));
     } 
}
```